# I need .htaccess to cache php pages, and expire them at the beginning of every hour (xx:00:00)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, caching, mod-expires

I want to cache a number of php pages that display different data at the beginning of every hour (xx:00:01)?

So far, I've found a way of cacheing a page +1hour from the time of accessing (or modifying the file), but if the user accesses the page at xx:59:00, then at xx+1:00:01, he will see the cache'd page data, not the newly displayed data.

What do I need to write to get a regular, "top-of-the-hour" cache expiry, preferably using .htaccess?

### Final code (non htaccess):

```
$nexthour = mktime(date("H")+1, 00, 20) - mktime();
header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=".$nexthour.", s-maxage=".$nexthour);
```

At the top of each page.

Comment: You might be able to do something with time-dependent rewrites: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/advanced.html#time-dependent

Comment: I don’t think this is possible using directives available in .htaccess alone. The only module I know that is capable of supporting server-side HTTP caching is [mod_cache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_cache.html), but its directives cannot be used in the .htaccess file context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can be done with htaccess but is kind of a pain.

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_WDAY} ^0$
RewriteCond yourfile.php - [E=daystring:SUN]
#etc (7x)

RewriteCond %{TIME_MON} ^0$
RewriteCond yourfile.php - [E=monthstring:JAN]
#etc (12x)

Header set "Expires" "%{daystring}, %{TIME_DAY} %{monthstring} %{TIME_YEAR} %{TIME_HOUR}:59:59 GMT "
```

Better to just do this in the PHP itself (after session_start()).

```
<?php
$nexthour = mktime (date("H"), 59, 59);
header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', $nexthour)); 
?>
```

Comment: This looks like the ticket :) Using the PHP code, would I also need to specify anything in .htaccess? Also, where do sessions come into this?

Comment: You only need the php. No need for any htaccess. If you are not using sessions (e.g. `$_SESSION['foo']`) you can forget I said that, as it doesn't apply.

Comment: Alright :) just tested it out, but ended up using Cache-control instead of Expires for it's independence from timezone constraints.

Comment: Whatever works for you. (Do note the use of `gmdate`, and not `date`)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to set up a cron job to run on the hour.  You could have it update static html files for all it cares, and then have Apache serve those.

(This wouldn't be a .htaccess based solution.)

Comment: I considered this, aswell as generating static files at the top of the php files, if they didn't exist for that hour, but I consider that approach a tad 'dirtier' than a client-side cache.

That, and I'm interested to see if .htaccess has such capabilities :P

Comment: Actually, thinking about it you could also have a cron'd php script which edits .htaccess, and changes the absolute expiry date of all php files :P Still looking for a solely htaccess solution though...